# Can't retrieve OUT parameters from stored procedures (MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql, django, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call stored procedure from MySQL and obtain OUT param.
I have code like this one,

Call procedure from Python

```
from django.db import connection
# ...
cursor = connection.cursor()
out_arg1 = ""
args = [in_arg1, in_arg2, out_arg1]
result = cursor.callproc('some_procedure', args)
print(args[2], result[2])
cursor.close()
# ...
```

MySQL procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `some_procedure`(IN `in_arg1` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `in_arg2` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, OUT `out_arg1` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN

 proc:begin
 set out_arg1="Result";
 end;

END;
```

I've checked *args* and the result returned by *cursor.callproc* method, but no data changed.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I've tried to call this procedure from MySQL console and everything is ok.

Comment: Have you tried doing cusor.execute("SELECT @out_arg1") after calling callproc method?

Comment: Nope, I've debugged through procedure call (with pdb) and `cursor.callproc` implementation generates custom names for parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this way

```
from django.db import connection
# ...
cursor = connection.cursor()
out_arg1 = ""
args = [in_arg1, in_arg2, out_arg1]
result = cursor.callproc('some_procedure', args)

cursor.execute('SELECT @some_procedure_2') 
print(cursor.fetchall())

#print(args[2], result[2])
cursor.close()
# ...
```

Comment: One little rectification - variable name is formed like this `_procname_n`. Anyway thank you, this method should work.